# Unable to scrape certain values of a website using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape the information inside of a particular set of p tags on a website and running into a lot of trouble.

My code looks like:

```
import urllib   
import re

def scrape():
        url = "https://www.theWebsite.com"

        statusText = re.compile('<div id="holdsThePtagsIwant">(.+?)</div>')
        htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
        htmltext = htmlfile.read()

        status = re.findall(statusText,htmltext)

        print("Status: " + str(status))
scrape()
```

Which unfortunately returns only: `"Status: []"`

However, that being said I have no idea what I am doing wrong because when I was testing on the same website I could use the code

```
statusText = re.compile('<a href="/about">(.+?)</a>')
```

instead and I would get what I was trying to, `"Status: ['About', 'About']"`

Does anyone know what I can do to get the information within the div tags? Or more specifically the single set of p tags the div tags contain? I've tried plugging in just about any values I could think of and have gotten nowhere. After Google, YouTube, and SO searching I'm running out of ideas now.

Comment: Did you check that htmltext is not empty in the first place?

Comment: @zx81 I don't see how it could be any different than when the a tags were there instead of the div tags. Wouldn't htmltext hold data in both or neither cases regardless?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you need to use Regex ? try checking out BeautifulSoup or Scrappy libraries in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for extracting information between html tags. Suppose you want to extract a division like this : `<div class='article_body' itemprop='articleBody'>...</div>`
then you can use beautifulsoup and extract this division by:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(<htmltext>) # creating bs object
ans = soup.find('div', {'class':'article_body', 'itemprop':'articleBody'})
```

also see the official [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) of bs4

as an example i have edited your code for extracting a division form an [article](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-02-20/chinese-group-considers-south-africa-platinum-bids-amid-strikes.html) of [bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com) 
you can make your own changes

```
import urllib   
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape():
    url = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-02-20/chinese-group-considers-south-africa-platinum-bids-amid-strikes.html'
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    ans = soup.find('div', {'class':'article_body', 'itemprop':'articleBody'})
    print ans
scrape()
```

You can BeautifulSoup from [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)

P.S. : I use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) and BeautifulSoup for web scraping and I am satisfied with it