# Extract text from Wikipedia html using Python

Tags: python, html, wikipedia

I am trying to look for a way to extract the main text of a Wikipedia article using python. I am aware of the "wikipedia" library, but in my case I already have downloaded the html page, and I just need to extract the text. I can't use that library because I need to use wikipedia page html that was downloaded some years ago so I can't download it from scratch.

Is there an "off the shelf" solution that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: As @CodeNinja says, [BeatifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a great tool, you can follow the tutorial [Easy Web Scraping with Python](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python) to learn more about this.

Comment: I've answered something similar here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671560/unable-to-scrape-certain-values-of-a-website-using-regex/23672014#23672014

Comment: I know about beautifulsoup and I have used it already in the past. What I was looking for is something that doesn't require me to look at which tags to consider, and also that maybe removes also all the wiki formatting as the references ([1],...) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

try **BeautifulSoup**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

respond = requests.get("http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/StackOverflow")
soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.text)
l = soup.find_all('p')
print l[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this python module:

```
pip install wikipedia
```